# IntelliJ IDEA Profiler error: Failed to generate a profiler dump: check that the JVM supports profiling

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, profiler

Any ideas how to set up a Kotlin project that that we can use a profiler? I don't really care which profiler is used (though looking for both memory and CPU profiling).

I've tried changing JVM versions and updating Kotlin to the latest version. I would update IntelliJ to 2023.1, but it doesn't support my current Kotlin version. I've checked the IntelliJ [page related to their profilers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#gradle-java-toolchains-support), but didn't find it helpful.

- Also, tried adding `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures`, but it gets stuck on 'Starting Gradle Daemon...'

Screenshot of error when trying to use IntelliJ Profiler:
[image: IntelliJ IDEA Profiler error: Failed to generate a profiler dump: check that the JVM supports profiling]

Screenshot of error when trying to Async Profiler:
[image: IntelliJ IDEA Async Profiler error: Invalid file format: No readable chunks in recording]

Details:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.5 Ultimate Edition
- In build.gradle.kts:

  - `plugins { kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22" }`
  - `kotlin { jvmToolchain(17) }` (Update: I can get it to work without this)
- openjdk-17.0.2
- Windows 10

UPDATE:
The above issues occur when trying to start a profiler on a unit test. But, if I start the unit test first, then attach the profiler... it's working... :shrug:

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with a sample project to reproduce and the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data). https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-300167/Cannot-open-profiling-report may be related.

Comment: I have the same problem, hope jetbrains will solve this